# Why new Date("1651214829629") show invalid date?

Tags: javascript, date, google-chrome, ecmascript-2016

When I run this code in the chrome console, it shows the following:

```
>new Date("1651214829629")

Invalid Date

>new Date(1651214829629)

Fri Apr 29 2022 14:47:09 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)

>new Date("110")

Wed Jan 01 0110 00:00:00 GMT+0805 (中国标准时间)
```

I'm not sure why `"1651214829629"` as a string is an invalid date, but `1651214829629` as a number is fine.

Comment: Not sure what you expect. Year 1651214829629? That's (too) far into the future

Answer (score 1):

Like Hao-Jung Hsieh said, if you give a string to `new Date()`, it will interpret it as a dateString, not a timestamp. To parse a dateString, `new Date()` will call `Date.parse()`, which is detailed in the ECMAScript docs [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date.parse). `Date.parse()` will first time to parse the dateString according to the [Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-date-time-string-format). The Date Time String Format says that if you only give one number, that number will be interpreted as the year, which is usally in the range 0-9999 (as defined by ISO 8601), but ECMAScript provides an extension to support years outside this range, which is detailed in the [Expanded Years](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-expanded-years) section. With this extension, the year can be be in the range -273,790 to 273,790.

So, when you provide run `new Date("1651214829629")`, Chrome will interpret 1651214829629 as a year. 1651214829629 is not in the acceptable range, therefore it is an invalid date.

Comment: ohooo. i always think it will turn number then formatter. tks

Comment: @iabuaz If my answer solved your issue, then consider marking it correct (the checkmark). This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a string, `new Date()` will think it's a dateString instead of a timestamp. `"110"` is meaning at 1:10. It just can't understand what is the dateString of `"1651214829629"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. I've tried out a few numbers, and it seems that any above 275760 does not work, but 275760 and below works. 275760 is being interpreted as `Tue Jan 01 275760 00:00:00 GMT-0600`

Comment: yee right! I misunderstood the formatting process!